# ¿Qué acepciones tiene el término "cañí"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado, españa, adjetivos, acepciones

Hoy me he tropezado con un artículo que decía

> Más allá **cañí**: lo más sobrenatural del cine español
>
> <sub>Fuente: [Cinemanía](http://cinemania.elmundo.es/galeria/mas-alla-cani-lo-mas-sobrenatural-del-cine-espanol/)</sub>

En principio, me pareció que simplemente decía algo así como:
`Más allá español/patrio: lo más sobrenatural del cine español`

pero al buscar "[cañí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7GClmV1)" en el diccionario me sorprendió que el significado aceptado (y única acepción) es

> 1. adj. **[gitano](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JDtQUsF)** (‖ de un pueblo originario de la India). U. t. c. s.

Y dudo mucho que ese artículo sobre cine quisiera decir "Más allá gitano" (o de etnia gitana o *[calé](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6lVhQhp)*). Ni siquiera "gitano" en su acepción de "que tiene gracia y arte para ganarse las voluntades de otros" me cuadra.

Buscando un poco más he encontrado los términos relacionados en "[España Cañí](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%B1a_ca%C3%B1%C3%AD)"

> España cañí (España **gitana**) es un pasodoble compuesto por [...]

Con lo que entiendo que *"cañí"* realmente se refiere a la etnia gitana, lo que añade más confusión al título del artículo sobre cine.

¿Tiene *"cañí"* otras acepciones aparte de la de "etnia gitana"? ¿O es que el artículo realmente se titula "Más allá **gitano**: lo más sobrenatural del cine español"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En otros diccionarios se le da la definición de típico o tradicional de España. En la enciclopedia [Espasa](http://espasa.planetasaber.com/encyclopedia/default.asp?idreg=59144&ruta=Buscador) por ejemplo:

> **cañí**
>
> Perteneciente o relativo a la España folclórica más tradicional

En [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/definicion/ca%C3%B1i) hay esta otra definición:

> 1. adj. col. Típico, folclórico: España cañí.

El buscador Google (no sé que diccionario utiliza) nos devuelve:

> **3.** `ESPAÑA` coloquial
>
> Que tiene los rasgos que se asocian a la España
>   folclórica y tradicional.

Supongo que el artículo al que te refieres le da el significado a la palabra *cañí* de algo típico español.